# Deploying NodeJS with MongoDB on Docker

Tags: node.js, docker

I am building a NodeJS application using MongoDB as the database. I am thinking that it will make more sense in terms of portability across different platforms and also versioning and comparison to have the application deployed in Docker. Going through various recommendations on internet, here are my specific questions :

(a) Do I copy my application code (nodejs) within Docker? Or do I keep Source code on the host machine and have the code base available to Docker using Volumes?  (*Just for experimenting, I had docker file instruction pulling the code from repository within the image directly. It works, but is it a good practice, or should I pull the code outside the docker container and make it available to docker container using Volumes / copy the code*)?

(b) When I install all my application dependencies, my node_module size explodes to almost 250 MB. So would you recommend that run npm install (for dependencies) as Docker step, which will increase the size of my image ? Or is there any other alternative that you can recommend?

(c) For connecting to the database, what will be the recommendation? Would you recommend, using another docker container with MongoDB image and define the dependency between the web and the db using docker? Along with that have configurable runtime property such that app in different environments (PROD, STAGE, DEV) can have the ability to connect to different database (mongodb).

Thoughts / suggestions greatly appreciated. I am sure, I may be asking questions which all of you may have run into at some point in time and have adopted different approaches, with pros and cons.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I copy my application code (nodejs) within Docker? Or do I keep
>   Source code on the host machine and have the code base available to
>   Docker using Volumes?

You should have the nodejs code inside the container. Keeping the source code on your machine will make your image not portable since if you switch to another machine, you need to copy the code there.

You can also pull the code directly into the container if you have git installed inside the container. But remember to remove the .git folder to have a smaller image.

> When I install all my application dependencies, my node_module size
>   explodes to almost 250 MB. So would you recommend that run npm install
>   (for dependencies) as Docker step, which will increase the size of my
>   image ? Or is there any other alternative that you can recommend?

This is node pulling over all the internet. You have to install you dependencies. However, you should run `npm cache clean --force` after the install to do some clean up to have a smaller image

> For connecting to the database, what will be the recommendation? Would
>   you recommend, using another docker container with MongoDB image and
>   define the dependency between the web and the db using docker? Along
>   with that have configurable runtime property such that app in
>   different environments (PROD, STAGE, DEV) can have the ability to
>   connect to different database (mongodb)

It is a good idea to create a new container for the database and connect your app to the database using docker [networks](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/). You can have multiple DB at the same time, but preferably keep one db container inside the network, and if you want to use another one, just remove the old one and add the new one to the network.

Comment: In a nutshell your recommendation is to add all of the following inside DockerFile :  {{(a) Get NodeJS docker image (b) Pull Code from repository (c) RUN npm install followed by npm clean. }} . Since we are pulling the dependencies as docker instruction, I will have very limited ability to keep the docker image size in check.

Comment: yes. In addition to what i mentioned, you should try to use a small node base image such as node:alpine. The size difference between node alpine image and node:latest is huge (23 MB compared to 266 MB). Thus if you don't need tools such as git, ... inside the container, definetly use the node:alpine as base image.

Answer (score 0):

**A**

*During development*

Using a directory in the host is fast. You modify your code, relaunch the docker image and it will start your app quickly.

*Docker image for production/deployement*

It is good to pull the code from git. it's heavier to run, but easier to deploy.

---

**B**

*During development*

Don't run `npm install` inside docker, you can handle the dependencies manually.

*Docker image for production/deployement*

Make a single `npm i` in image building, because it's supposed to be static anyway.

**More explanation**

When you are developing, you change your code, use a new package, adapt your `package.json`, update packages ...

You basically need to control what happen with `npm`. It is easier to interact with it if you can directly execute commands lines and access the files (outside docker in local directory). You make your change, you relaunch your docker and it get started!

When you are deploying your app, you don't have the need to interact with `npm` modules. You want a packaged application with an appropriate version number and release date that do not move and that you can rely on.

Because `npm` is not 100% trustworthy, it happen that with exact same `package.json` some stuff you get as you `npm i` makes the application to crash. So I would not recommend to use `npm i` at every application relaunch or deployement, because imagine some package get fucked up, you gotta rush to find out a soluce. Moreover there is no need at all to reload packages that should be the exact same (they should!). It's not in deployement that you want to update the package! But in your developement environment where you can `npm update` safely and test everything up.

(Sorry about english!)

---

**C**

Use two docker image and connect them using a docker network. So you can deploy easily your app anywhere.

---

Some commands to help maybe about Docker networking! (i'm actually using it in my company)

```
// To create your own network with docker

sudo docker network create --subnet=172.42.0.0/24 docker-network

// Run the mondogb docker
sudo docker run -i -t --net docker-network --ip 172.42.0.2 -v ~/DIRECTORY:/database mongodb-docker

// Run the app docker
sudo docker run -i -t --net docker-network --ip 172.42.0.3 -v ~/DIRECTORY:/local-git backend-docker
```

Comment: Could you please throw some more light on your comment on point # B -  

**Don't run npm install inside docker, you can handle the dependencies manually.**

Docker image for production/deployement -

**Make a single npm i in image building, because it's supposed to be static anyway. "**